# the data is not loaded and it is not display in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

this result of the fetch.php that contain on the data from mysql database  page

[{"id":"1","name":"Moblie phone","price":"3000","image":"mobil1","desc":"samasong mobile garand prime 2+"},{"id":"2","name":"Watch","price":"200","image":"watch","desc":"modern watch its color is gold"},{"id":"3","name":"Labtop","price":"4000","image":"labtop","desc":"hp labtop core i5 space 500gb "},{"id":"4","name":"moble lite","price":"1999","image":"mobil2","desc":"moble lite sterrr"}]

this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>shoping cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="functions/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Shopping cart application by angularjs and php</h2>
    <div class="container" ng-app="shoppingcart" ng-controller="shoppingcartcontroller">
        <div class="row " >
            <div class="box col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px"
            ng-repeat="p in products">


                    {{p.name}}
                    {{p.price}}

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

this angularjs code

```
<script >
    var app=angular.module("shoppingcart",[]); 

    app.controller("shoppingcartcontroller",function($http,$scope){

        $scope.loadproduct=function(){
            $http.get("fetch.php").then(function(response){
                    $scope.products=response.data.data;
                    console.log($scope.products);
                });
         };
     });
</script>
```

Comment: And where you call `$scope.loadproduct`?

Comment: thanks when i remove the loadproduct function the code is excute and display the data correct. thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need this loadproduct function?

Please only this in your controller:

```
        $http.get("fetch.php").then(function(response){
                $scope.products=response.data.data;
                console.log($scope.products);
            });
```

In addition, take in consideration to check whether you need to define '$scope.products' as an empty array outside the scope of your get request.